# How to extract data from a HTTP Post method in a MVC Controller Method?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I was trying to implement some client side logging for a web page that we are building. The idea is to some specific error events on the client side, which would occur when some critical information is not being returned from the server side (the information on the page is aggregated from multiple services).

On my client side Javascript, I have :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'MyURL',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'MyErrorMessage',
});
```

And on my server side controller, I want to have :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "MyURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView logErrorMessages(String errorMessage)
{
     /* Log the error message using the server side logging framework */
}
```

Now, I am not exactly sure how to access the error message string in the controller. I tried the above approach and the String was 'null'. One other approach I considered was to put the error message string into the request URL as a `@RequestParam`, as defined here : [here](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/tutorials/spring/mvc_4.html).
But I am slightly squeamish about doing that since, I have the feeling that messages should not really be a part of URL parameters. I am sure I am missing something very obvious here (like creating a error message object as a part of the 'Model' or something similar), but my problem is that I am new to the MVC and Web development world and haven't looked at the Model/View code, only the 'Controller' code. Any tips which would put me on the right track are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @ModelAttribute annotation:

client side

data: "error='System Error'"
...

server side

logErrorMessage(@ModelAttribute(name="error") String errorMessage ...